# Change priority rule of a Queue block at runtime in Anylogic

Tags: simulation, reinforcement-learning, anylogic, agent-based-modeling, discrete

I am trying to implement reinforcement learning in Anylogic using pathmind library, the RL agent can take either of two actions which is changing the priority rule of a Queue block.

I have a Queue block where I'm using priority-based queueing. I have two priority rules: using *agent's departure date* & *agent's wait time*. I want to either of these rules during runtime using another function called doAction(action). A value 0 or 1 will be passed to this function. The function body would be like this:

```
doAction(action){

if(action==0){
//set departure_date as priority rule of Queueblock}

else{
//set wait_time as priority rule of Queueblock}

}
```

The expression of my queue block is given here. [image: QueueBlock].

RL parameters are mentioned here. [image: RL Params]

What should be the code to set priority rule dynamically from the doAction(action) function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest to rather make the priority rule dynamic inside the queue.

I assume you have some agent with a field for departureTime as well as for waitingTime.

Then you can do something like the following:
You simply have a different priority level for each agent if the priority option changes.
Here I am using boolean useDaprtureTime, but you can make it as complex as you need and even have a function in the "Agent Priority" field that returns the priority level.

Just remember that you need to call queue.sortAgents() if you change the rule since only the new agents that arrive are sorted, not the entire list of agents waiting in the queue since this will be too resource-intensive.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

To use priorities, you specify an expression to determine the priority of the agent in the Queue's "Agent priority" or "Agent 1 is preferred to agent 2" property (depending what priority scheme you're using).

So have that expression be calling a function (defined within the agent type in question) which returns either the departure date or wait-time alternative.

Also, you didn't say whether this is a global setting --- i.e., use either departure or wait-time-based priorities for the whole run --- or could change dynamically; if you want the latter, you potentially need to call the `sortAgents` function of the Queue block (which might be inside a Service or Seize block, depending what you're doing) at the appropriate times (i.e., when your prioritisation scheme changes) to re-calculate all the priorities for agents currently waiting in the queue.

**EDIT**: I see from your other comment that you're trying to use reinforcement learning, presumably learning how to make a decision on how to prioritise the agents. (You should put that in an edit to your question since it's pretty important and relevant!)

So if you view the queue as the 'learning agent', you need to separate the learning action (which will set up / decide which prioritisation scheme you're using) from then using that scheme in the prioritisation.

This depends on whether you're using a Queue on its own (with priority based or agent comparison queueing), or you're doing this within a Service or Seize block. It matters because the on-enter action of the latter runs *before* the priority calculation expression but, with a plain Queue, it runs *after* the priority calculation.

### Case 1: Using Service or Seize block

Have the on-enter action be the RL action which would then, say, set some variable to say which prioritisation scheme it had chosen and then call `sortAgents` on its embedded queue (`self.queue`) to recalc all the priorities. Then have switches in the priority calculation expression as above to do the calculation for the incoming agent using the required scheme.

### Case 2: Using a plain Queue block

As above, but do the prioritisation scheme decision in the on-at-exit actions of all immediately preceding blocks (i.e., so that this is run just before the agent arrives at the Queue block and has its prioritisation allocated).

Comment: Hello @sprossiter, Thank you for your response. I understand that I can call the doAction(action) function from 'Agent Priority' field of Queue block, but I need to know which action is being taken by the RL agent to pass as an argument at every step.  I can think of two ways: i) Get RL agent's action at each step and then call doAction() from Queue block or ii) RL agent calls doAction() and somehow alters the priority rule of Queue block (either '30-dep_date' or 'waitTime'). But I don't know what code to use for either of the ways.

Comment: I did explain that in my answer but I've clarified it since it's slightly different depending on whether you're using a plain Queue or Service/Seize blocks (which have a prioritised queue inside) for your prioritisation.

Answer (score -2):

You can always use 2 queue blocks and send agents to only one using a `SelectOutput` block in front of them.

Each agent decides which queue to use based on your conditions.

Comment: I am trying to implement reinforcement learning in anylogic. So I need to specify the action in the above function. In your suggested method, can you please the code that I can write in the doAction() such that my purpose is achieved.